# Java 8 DateTimeFormatter performance

Tags: java, performance, java-8, date

I have below code which is predominantly the most expensive in terms of time complexity in my application.

```
public class Test {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter SQL_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Instant start = Instant.now();
        try {
            String parsedDate = parseISO8601UtcDateToSqlDateFormat("2000-01-01T00:00:00Z");
            System.out.println(parsedDate);
        } finally {
            long timeTaken = Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).toMillis();
            System.out.println("\n\nFinished processing in: "+timeTaken+ " ms!\n"); 
        }
    }

    public static String parseISO8601UtcDateToSqlDateFormat(String param) {

        TemporalAccessor accessor = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.parse(param);
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.from(accessor), ZoneOffset.UTC);
        return dateTime.format(SQL_FORMATTER);

    }

}
```

Date time formatting is consuming **16ms** at the minimum.

Whereas my complete application which does a lot of complex processing is done in less than **1ms**.

P.S: Question is not related to benchmarking, I just want to understand whether date time parsing with java 8 is really this expensive or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: How are you benchmarking this?

Comment: Assuming you're correctly benchmarking this, is 16ms *really* a problem?

Comment: *Whereas my complete application which does a lot of complex processing is done in less than 1ms.* So according to you, *lot of complex processing* done by your logic is faster than these four lines of code? Are we talking about the **for loops** and **if statements** as a complex process?

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(SQLFormatConstants.JAVA_DATE_FORMAT);` This can be `static final` I believe. The new java 8 datetime api compiles such pattern, and you're compiling one everytime you want to format a date.

Comment: @sturcotte06 Joda caches patterns. Does Java Time not?

Comment: @sturcotte06 That's very obvious.. which I already tried before posting the question. For me even a single ms is too much

Comment: Your benchmark is probably not giving the right result. In my own benchmark with JMH I get about 1ns (_not_ ms) on average per call, which is completely neglect-able.

Comment: "_Question is not related to benchmarking, I just want to understand whether date time parsing with java 8 is really this expensive or am I doing something wrong._" -> you **are** doing something wrong, your measurement is wrong. I imagine you are measuring classloading.

Comment: Of your 16 ms, how many are spent doing the timing, mostly inside `Instant.now()`?

Comment: You shouldn’t need to format your date-time for SQL. Your JDBC driver will happily accept an `Instant` object (if version 4.2 compliant, which it probably is).

Comment: You're still missing a lot of class loading at that point, you can check by using `-XX:+TraceClassLoading`. You're also measuring the call to `System.out.println` which takes a long time. It's just a lot more reliable to use something like [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), which has most of the functionality built in.

Comment: "_See where I'm noting the start time. I believe all class loading is done by that time._" - what makes you believe that? How about profiling/JIT? You are benchmarking the JVM not your code - listen to what literally _everyone_ is telling you.

Comment: Okay, you have now static formatters which is good practice for immutable objects. But you should really use `System.nanoTime()` instead of `Duration`-expression for minimizing the impact on benchmark results. JMH is usually better for this purpose. And if you still think after having done this that you have a performance problem then you might try my lib Time4J which contains a fast format and parse engine using [ChronoFormatter](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/format/expert/ChronoFormatter.html).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter SQL_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(SQLFormatConstants.JAVA_DATE_FORMAT);

private String parseISO8601UtcDateToSqlDateFormat(String param) {
    TemporalAccessor accessor = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.parse(param);
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.from(accessor), ZoneOffset.UTC);
    return dateTime.format(SQL_FORMATTER);
}
```

New Java 8 Time API have stateless and immutable formatters. Custom formatters should be compiled once and stored in a constant (Like `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`).

Comment: Well the benchmark you're doing makes no sense. Have you considered that the formatter might have lazy initialization? Have you considered that a JVM needs to warmup? You need to do at least 10k iterations without recording any timestamps. Then do 10k iterations with a single timestamp. Split the time range on your 10k iterations. If it still gives you 16ms by iteration, then we'll keep searching for a solution.

Comment: Also, use `System.nanoTime()` for benchmarking (or Guava's `Stopwatch`).